# Should I always return a meaningful value from a function : PHP

Tags: php

I have a function which writes a piece of code into a dynamically generated PHP file.As per the PEAR coding standards,we should always attempt to return a meaningful value from our function.Now , if i have to return a meaningful value 
from my function , how whould i rewrite this code ? Should I always return true OR true if the function executes successfully and false if it doesn't.

Please find my code below :

```
function AUTOCODE_writeFile($filename, $code)
{

    $handle = fopen($_POST['db']."/".$filename, "w");

    fwrite($handle, $code);

    fclose($handle);    

}
```

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is `return 'This may or may not have worked, I cannot tell because I dont check for any errors anywhere';`

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the return value of the fwrite call in a variable and return that?

Says http://php.net/fwrite:

> fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error.

This way you can evaluate whether or not writing to the file has been successful from the return value.